# Sharepoint designer doesn't show all fields of current item in workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

When creating a workflow using Sharepoint Designer (linked to a form library) none of my fields from my form show up when I use actions like "set field in current item" or "update list item". The only two fields that show are

"Title"
"Name (for use in forms)"

I have already tried to upload the form as a site content type but was still not able to get the items on my form (using the solution posted here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/37db5742-79ba-49cb-bda5-69172786a339/spd-field-lookup-problem-set-field-in-current-item?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)

please help me ,this problem is hurting my brain :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually doing the thing mentioned here fixed my problem

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/37db5742-79ba-49cb-bda5-69172786a339/spd-field-lookup-problem-set-field-in-current-item?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

at first it seemed like it was not working but I just had to refresh the page -very intelligent mistake :'(

Anyways I'm happy that the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

This is something which is related to the Refresh a page. Or What you can do is close the site in the Sharepoint designer and then re connect the site. Sometimes refreshing the page does not seem to work.

Comment: I guess that could have been the problem too. Thanks for the insight